How to run a jenkins subproject within the same pod as the main project?
I have a Jenkins freestyle project that runs on k8s slave pod. Now the main project has another subproject, which essentially clone/pull files from github, meaning the files pulled by the subproject are required for the main project.
The problem I'm facing is that, when I run the build, both the project and subproject are running in different pods,so the files downloaded by the subproject is not accessible to the main project.
job('main-project') {    
    steps {
        downstreamParameterized {

            trigger('upstrea_job1') {  ----> pull/clone a git repo into the workspace of the main project
                 parameters {
                    predefinedProp('customWorkspace', '${WORKSPACE}/${BUILD_NUMBER}/survey_vm_conf')
                }
            }

        }

Is there any workaround I could do ?

Define Agent for the stages you want to run in a single pod. I would suggest a single pod file with Kubernetes agent.
pipeline {
  agent {
    kubernetes {
      yaml '''
        apiVersion: v1
        kind: Pod
        spec:             
          containers:
          - name: docker
            image: ci:latest
            tty: true
        '''
    }
  }
  
  stages {
    stage('Stage name') {
    steps {
        downstreamParameterized {

            trigger('upstrea_job1') {  ----> pull/clone a git repo into the workspace of the main project
                 parameters {
                    predefinedProp('customWorkspace', '${WORKSPACE}/${BUILD_NUMBER}/survey_vm_conf')
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

It will create a single pod whenever a new pipeline runs and all your Step/Jobs can use a single Pod to manage the workspace.

Sharing workspaces is possible, taker a look at the External Workspace Manager plugin, it's even mentioned in the official Jenkins docs, but it is not a popular plugin and it is not a common thing to do. A better way to reuse code is to lift it into a shared library.
